# Django Formset: Change Widget depending on value

Tags: django, formset

I'm not using `ModelForm`. I'm passing the values to the formset form using `instance`. Is there anyway to change the widget of the field dynamically depending on the value of the queryset?

What I want to do is display either a form element or just text, depending on whether a flag is true or not.

```
    initial=[
         {
            'name': u'Foo',
            'date1': 'Jan-13',
            'date2': 'Feb-13',
            'value1': 11.32,
            'value2': 54.13, # e.g add PlainTextWidget to this field
            # ...
         },
         {
            'name': u'Bar',
            'date1': 'Jan-13',
            'date2': 'Feb-13',
            'value1': 1,
            'value2': 54.13,
            # ...
         },
         # ...

    ]
    form = MonthlyFormset(initial = initial)
```

Comment: How are you rendering the form? Please add the template code. If you are rendering each field, then its possible to put an if condition in the template itself.

Comment: I'm looping it. But I could render each field individually, but that would require a lot of if statements in the template code. I also would need a flag for each field. There is no other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to change widget is in your view:

```
initial=[
     {
        'name': u'Foo', ...
        'value2': 54.13, # e.g add PlainTextWidget to this field
        # ...
     },
     {
        'name': u'Bar', ...
        'value2': 54.13,
        # ...
     },
     # ...

]

formset = MonthlyFormset(initial = initial )

for form in formset:
    #check for flag:
    if form.fields['name'].initial = u'Bar':
        #changing widget
        form.base_fields['name'].widget = PlainTextWidget()
```

I have not tested this code, come back with comments. Also, I'm not sure **what is `PlainTextWidget`, I hope this will be a custom widget wrote by you.**